# Why does AsynchronousSocketChannel fire its "completed" function on disconnect?

Tags: java

The `AsynchronousSocketChannel` fires its `CompletionHandler`'s `completed(Integer result, ByteBuffer attachment)` function, when the Telnet client disconnects.

The `result` Integer is a compeletly random number.

I cannot make difference between receiving a new message and the client disconection. How can I solve this problem?
How can I filter this event, so I can make difference between an actual message and the garbage random executions?

Here is the full code:

```
final AsynchronousServerSocketChannel serverSocket = AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.open().bind(new InetSocketAddress(4242));
System.out.println("Starting server...");

serverSocket.accept(null, new CompletionHandler<AsynchronousSocketChannel, Void>() {
    @Override
    public void completed(AsynchronousSocketChannel clientSocket, Void attachment) {
        System.out.println("Client connected");

        final int clientndex = clients.size();
        clients.put(clientndex, "Something...");

        final ByteBuffer clientBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(256);

        clientSocket.read(clientBuffer, null, new CompletionHandler<Integer, ByteBuffer>() {
            @Override
            public void completed(Integer result, ByteBuffer attachment) { //### This fires randomly
                clientBuffer.flip();

                try {
                    System.out.println("LEN" + result + " message received from " + clientndex + ": " + bufferDecoder.decode(clientBuffer).toString());
                } catch (CharacterCodingException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Bad encoding");
                }

                clientBuffer.clear();
            }

            @Override
            public void failed(Throwable exc, ByteBuffer attachment) {
                System.out.println("Read error");
            }
        });

        serverSocket.accept(null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void failed(Throwable exc, Void attachment) {
        System.out.println("Conn error");
    }
});
```

Comment: A "completely random number"? What are some of the values you've been seeing?

Comment: When I do NOT perform sending data, just connecting and disconnecting with Telnet one after another, theese are the numbers of the `Integer result`: "5 36 145 31 28 45 34 34 12 22 30"

Comment: *"Here is the full code:"* Apparently not. What is `clients`?

Comment: A TreeMap. Never used. Just for experiment, it can be deleted, still the bug occurs.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousSocketChannel.html#read%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%5b%5d,%20int,%20int,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,%20A,%20java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler%29), the result won't be random, it will be the number of bytes successfully read (presumably prior to the socket being disconnected):

> The result passed to the completion handler is the number of bytes read or -1 if no bytes could be read because the channel has reached end-of-stream.

I believe it must be that the client(s) are sending you data you're not expecting, and the value is in fact correct.

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought first. ...but the `completed` also fires on disconnetion when I did not send anyting prior to that. Just connect and disconnect, nothing else.

Comment: @ÁgotaHorváth: Strange, I don't see that behavior. If I turn that into a program and run it, and use `telnet localhost 4242` in another window, I never seen a read completion if I never send anything from the client (and I do see a read completion, with the correct `result` value, if I do). Sounds like the clients are sending something you're not expecting.

Comment: I discovered: I am using Mac and the Terminal application sends a bunch of spaces when I quit. Unbelievable.

Comment: @ÁgotaHorváth: OMG :-) Well, that explains it!

Comment: The byte that was sent: "4". ASCII Character code "4" = EOT = End Of Transmission. :)